# is light-wallet has problem for keys and addresses?

Tags: wallets

somebody said for light wallet on github, the address generated and private key is wrong? I saw on post, is that true?

Comment: Could you provide a link to "light wallet"?

Comment: https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet  this is the link. Is there any other wallet can be compatible with this wallet and i can import the seeds to the wallet? I saw the phrase and password field which other wallets does not have such as metamask